# Modify Existing Code to Write to Columns

Tags: python, csv

I am looking to change the below code so that instead of writing row by row with the contents of `values` the code will only write on one row and will separate all contents of `values` with a comma, thus making all of the values be in columns in the .csv instead of rows (as it is right now).

```
for row in values:
     writer.writerow({'Variable name': row, 'Variable value': values[row]})
     if row == 'C_SerialNumber':
          logging.info("Writing data to csv file for SN: %s"%values[row])
```

What would be the easiest way to do this? I would essentially want the following:

```
Variable name, Variable value
Name1, Value1
Name2, Value2
...
NameX, ValueX
```

Turned into: (I would already have the .csv headings created and would just want the `value` section appended.

```
Name1, Name2, ... , NameX
Value1, Value2, ... , ValueX
```

The `values` data would then just be looped and appended to the existing .csv file.

Is this possible, and if so, easy to do?

Comment: Have a look at [csv.DictWriter](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.dictwriter#csv.DictWriter).

Answer (score 1):

```
writer.writerow(values.keys())
writer.writerow(values.values())
```

Comment: I didn't think this would work because of ordering issues, but turns out for a dictionary `mydict` `dict(zip(mydict.keys(), mydict.values())) == mydict` valuates to `True`.  Who knew?

Comment: Dictionaries just hash the keys, so it makes sense that order is consistent. I did test it first though... ;-)

Comment: @D Yeah, but dictionaries other than `OrderedDict` explicitly aren't ordered, which is why I wasn't sure at first.